# How do I bind XF86XK_AudioMicMute to an action in XMonad?

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xmonad

I am toying with switching back to XMonad from dwm, but one of the issues I ran into during my last stint with XMonad was that my micmute key (my keyboard has one), did not work since XMonad's [Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/X11/Graphics-X11-ExtraTypes-XF86.html) does not include the KeySym for `XF86XK_AudioMicMute`.

Does this mean that it is impossible for me to bind this key to an action in XMonad? Note that the keysym is present in `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h` (and resultingly, I am able to bind it in dwm without issue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86 does not appear to provide an `XF86XK_AudioMicMute` KeySym. Either this was an oversight (maybe the MicMute key keysym was added after the Haskell module was written) or an intentional decision (perhaps because the Mic Mute key is so uncommon).

Either way, luckily, there is a way to bind keys in Haskell without a KeySym: you use the actual event identifier (for which the KeySym from `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h` just provides a macro); in fact, the KeySyms in Graphics.X11.ExtraTypes.XF86 are just macros for the event identifiers as well.

Using `xev` (the `Xorg` component tool) will allow you to check the key event (or KeySym name) associated with a particular key press. Once you know the KeySym name if the event identifier itself is not visible for some reason, you can check `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h` to determine the exact event identifier. On my system, the following line exists in that header:

```
#define XF86XK_AudioMicMute 0x1008FFB2   /* Mute the Mic from the system */
```

That means, on my system (and note that these keysyms are vendor-specific), `XF86XK_AudioMicMute` has the event identifier `0x1008FFB2`. Now, like magic, you can throw the event identifier in your `xmonad.hs` which might look something like this:

```
myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask}) = M.fromList $
    [ ... <snip>
    , ((0, xF86XK_AudioMute), spawn $ "pactl -- set-sink-mute   1 toggle")
    , ((0, XF86XK_AudioMicMute), spawn $ "pactl -- set-source-mute 2 toggle")
    , ... <snip>
    ]
```

And voila! You are now the proud owner of your very own functional MicMute key!

In addition, this strategy can be used for any key which does not have a public KeySym but still has a recognizable event identifier.

For a similar answer (one through which I originally discovered this feature), see [this Superuser.SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/389829/316219).